# Compact key value store in Rust

Tags: rust, key-value-store

I'm working on a Rust project that collects daily statistics for a web-site (number of requests, number of unique users, average latency etc.). I'd like to store this data in a compact key-value store where the key is a date (or a date string) and the value is an object that contain the statistics. I also need this data to be persisted to a file.

I don't have any special performance or storage requirements. That's why I don't want to use major DBs like Redis, MongoDB or Cassandra that require a separate installation and significant resources to run. I'd like something much simpler and lightweight.

The ideal solution for me would be a library that can read and write key-value data and persist it into a file. The data size I'm aiming for is around 1000-2000 records.

Can you recommend a library I can use?

Comment: I think this question should be asked at [software-recommandations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Could you please move this question to there.

Comment: I already got an answer, but I'll keep that in mind for the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [PickleDB-rs](https://github.com/seladb/pickledb-rs). I think it answers most of your requirements. PickleDB-rs is a Rust version of [Python's PickleDB](https://pythonhosted.org/pickleDB/). It's intended for small DBs (I think 1000-2000 records should be ok) and the performance isn't guaranteed to be as great as large scale DBs, but for the purpose of dumping daily web-site stats into a file it should be sufficient.